# Detect broken links in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, hyperlink, url-rewriting

Do you know any script to detect broken links in a site developed in codeigniter (with url rewriting)?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I have used [Xenu's Link Sleuth](http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html) in the past. You give it a URL and it will crawl the site looking for broken links. I'm not entirely sure if this is what the question is after though. Could you clarify please?

This is what it looks like:
[alt text http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/9/9f/Xenu_screenshot.png](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/9/9f/Xenu_screenshot.png)